# I tried to install "ubuntu tweak" but i can't find it now, how to fix this?

Tags: tweak

After I installed tweak using "***Sudo apt-get install tweak***" i went to dash home and i searched for "***Ubuntu tweak***" but it did not find it, so i tried to install it again but it told me "***tweak is already the newest version.***"

what should i do?

Comment: tweak is actually a hex editor.  Open a terminal window and try typing 'tweak'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said tweak is not the same as ubuntu-tweak.
I'm using the ppa provided by Ding Zhou:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Answer (score 0):

tweak is not the same as ubuntu-tweak.

ubuntu-tweak is not in the standard repositories. You can download it from here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak

Comment: yes sorry, i meant "ubuntu tweak" and i installed it finally using "synaptic". synaptic is awesome.